# What is wrong with this functions recursion? (setTimeout issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, timeout, marquee

I am writing a marquee script because I do not like the fact that with most marquee scripts when the marquee reaches the last item (thinking using a ul, so last item is the last li), it waits till that item is off screen, and then resets the position of the ul, and starts the scrolling all over agian.

My approach is to create a clone of the ul, append it after the current ul, and start it scrolling, then delete the original ul once it is completely hidden.

This works almost perfect except for one thing. When you call the function it generates the time required for a setTimout. This setTimout is used to create the new UL and set it moving.

This works fine for the first loop, but then glitches up.

It is a bit hard to explain, but it seems to on the second time the timeout should be called, instead of waiting for the time, it just calls itself instantly. Please see http://webspirited.com/marquee.html for an example

For a working example. The javascript code is as follows:

```
var count = 0;
$('document').ready(function () {
    //generate some random rows
    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    $('.ulscroll').append('<li>Content ' + i + '</li>');
    //add one row so we can see its the last
    $('.ulscroll').append('<li>Last Item</li>');

    //set the ul's width
    var width = 0;
    $('.ulscroll').children('li').each(function () {
        width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    log('ul width: ' + width);
    $('.ulscroll').width(width);

    //activate the marquee              
    marquee('.ulscroll', 1, false);
});

function marquee(id, speed, sub) {
    //next two lines debugging purposes only
    count += 1;
    log('Marquee ran ' + count + ' times');

    //store copy of speed sent it(to pass for recursion)
    var s1 = speed;
    //set speed to 10*
    speed = speed * 10;

    //store parent width, and own width (if sub then add on width of parent div)
    var pwidth = $(id).parent('div').outerWidth();
    var width = (sub ? $(id).width() + pwidth : $(id).width());

    //set timeout
    var t = (width - pwidth) * speed;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var clone = $(id).clone().css('left', pwidth);
        $(id).addClass('oldul');
        $(id).after(clone);
        marquee(id + ':not(.oldul)', s1, true);
    }, t);

    $(id).animate({
        left: '-=' + width
    }, width * speed, 'linear', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

function log(text) {
    $('#log').append('<div>' + text + '</div>');
}
```

---

**Solution**
The issue was caused by passing the selector in with :not(.ulold);
Here is the revised setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var clone = $(id).clone().css('left', pwidth);
  $(id).addClass('oldul');
  var idx = id.split(':');
  idx = idx[0];
  log('idx: '+idx);
  $(idx).after(clone);
  marquee(idx+':not(.oldul)', s1, true);
},t);
```

Comment: Well this probably isn't the problem, but "s1" should probably be a  local variable (`var s1 = ...;`).

Comment: @pointy, You are correct, on both counts :)

Comment: If you want a function to be executed at regular intervals (well, as regular as JS can get), use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval), not `setTimeout`.

Comment: @outis: Thankyou for the suggestion however it is not regular intervals as the first time it is one length, the next time it will be a different length.

Comment: @Hailwood: After the first time, it runs at regular intervals, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: In its current state yes, However, this will actually be setup to take either an ajax call for the data, or just loop its own data, hence, if the ajax data is different, it will be a different interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, most likely, lies with this code..

```
    var clone = $(id).clone().css('left', pwidth);
    $(id).addClass('oldul');
```

The fact that you are re-using the selector messes things up because the original selector matches a lot of things as time progresses..

In the initial call use `marquee('.ulscroll:not(.oldul)', 1, false);`

Comment: you were correct.

after the second time it would become  id:not(.ulold):not(.ulold);

Comment: Cheers! My code was actually very rough as I was only getting the basics of it moving correctly, however you have saved me some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use a good debugger, such as [Firebug](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/build_better_pages_with_firebug/). You'll see that eventually the animation end callback (the one that removes the elements matching the selector) gets called before the anonymous timeout function (the one that calls `marquee`).

An issue with the code on the sample page (but not in the posted code): `tout` is local to each invocation of `marquee`. The `clearTimeout(tout)` call does nothing.

Lastly, please don't use a marquee. It has [usability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element#Usability_problems) problems: moving text is harder to read, causes distraction, and will always move either too quickly for some readers or too slowly for some readers.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I have not run into the issue of the callback getting called first, also with regards to the marquee, I am making a complete clone of the twitter theme (dont bother asking why) But, as the twitter theme uses this style of marquee, so must I ;) I would never use a marquee on my own projects as I completely agree with you :)